# Installing Emacs Evil Mode for Windows

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I want to install Emacs Evil mode in Windows, but I can't find any documentation on the subject. Does Evil mode exist for Windows? If so how do I install?

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in trying evil mode, I suggest you use the excellent bootstrap available here: https://github.com/bling/emacs-evil-bootstrap.

Two scenarios:

1. If you don't have a `.emacs` or `init.el` file yet, simply copy the supplied `init.el` file into your `emacs.d` directory. Emacs will automatically load evil mode when you next open the program.
   (If you are running Windows, your `emacs.d` directory will probably be located at `C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d`.)
2. If you already have a `.emacs` or `init.el` config file, open up the github `init` file and copy across the code it contains to your own config file (if you already have some of this code, or some code that does the same job, you don't have to repeat it):

   ```
   (require 'package)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives
                '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

   ;;; from purcell/emacs.d
   (defun require-package (package &optional min-version no-refresh)
     "Install given PACKAGE, optionally requiring MIN-VERSION.
   If NO-REFRESH is non-nil, the available package lists will not be
   re-downloaded in order to locate PACKAGE."
     (if (package-installed-p package min-version)
         t
       (if (or (assoc package package-archive-contents) no-refresh)
           (package-install package)
         (progn
           (package-refresh-contents)
           (require-package package min-version t)))))

   (package-initialize)

   (require-package 'evil)

   (setq evil-search-module 'evil-search
         evil-want-C-u-scroll t
         evil-want-C-w-in-emacs-state t)

   (require 'evil)
   (evil-mode t)
   ```

   Again, just follow these steps, and emacs will automatically load evil mode when you next open the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it through ELPA, or by cloning the repository to a local directory. It's no different on Windows from any other operating system.

What's the problem you're having? The [home page](http://gitorious.org/evil/pages/Home) has the simple installation instructions.

Comment: I couldn't connect to the git repository so I downloaded the tarball. Which directory do I put the extracted file? The Evil page only has instructions for Linux systems.

Comment: Put it wherever you want, the only requirement is that you add that directory to `load-path`.